# How to write disk benchmarking software?

Tags: file-handling, file-storage, benchmarking

I am coding a disk (HDD/SSD) benchmarking software. I have a few questions on how a disk should be benchmarked (regardless of programming language used).

This is my pseudo code for testing *sequential write speed*:

```
total_size = 1GiB
block_size = 1MiB
random_byte_array[2**30] = an array of random bytes of total size 1GiB

my_file = open_new_file_for_binary_write()
start_stopwatch()

for i in range(total_size / block_size):
    my_file.write(random_byte_array, length=block_size, offset=i*block_size)

stop_stopwatch()
my_file.close()

result = total_size / stopwatch.elapsed_time_in_seconds()
```

My questions on this pseudo code are:

1. Should I write into file like above where I keep writing without allocating the file myself, and let the OS allocate the necessary size as I write or should I create a 1GiB sized file before starting to write, then open that file and write into that pre-allocated file?
2. Should I start stopwatch like above or should I include opening/closing times of the file into my calculation?

This is my pseudo code for testing *random 4KiB write speed with 1 thread and 1 queue depth*:

```
total_size = 1GiB
block_size = 4KiB
random_byte_array[2**30] = an array of random bytes of total size 1GiB

start_stopwatch()

for i in range(total_size / block_size):
    my_file = open_new_file_for_binary_write()
    my_file.write(random_byte_array, length=block_size, offset=i*block_size)
    my_file.close()

stop_stopwatch()

result = total_size / stopwatch.elapsed_time_in_seconds()
```

My questions on this pseudo code are:

3. Should I create and write into new files like I do above, or should I create a 1 GiB file, then write random positions of that file so that I only open a file 1 time instead of opening/closing new files "total_size / block_size" times?
4. Should I include file opening/closing times like above or not?

And my questions for *multiple queue depth*:

5. How do we implement writing with multiple queue depths? Do we do that with multiple threads? But some benchmarking programs have tests with 32 queue depth and only 1 thread, how is that implemented? How do they send multiple write requests without creating multiple threads?
6. What is the difference between using multiple queue depth and multiple threads?
7. When we are benchmarking with multiple queue depths or multiple threads do we include file opening/closing times?

PS: I am using C# for implementing my software but I guess my questions are language-agnostic.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to test? All of your code tests the filesystem implementation as much as it tests the harddisk. Your second test also seems as if it will test the performance of `file.open` and `file.close` much more than it will actually test the disk. In fact, in a system with enough free RAM, *none* of your operations will ever hit the disk, they will be performed purely in cache.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am basically trying to do what other disk benchmark programs are doing, like CrystalDiskMark or AS SSD Bench. On C# you can set buffer size or flush the contents of the stream using Flush() method to make sure the changes are written to the file.

Comment: `FileStream.Flush()` will only flush the `FileStream`, it will *not* ensure that the data actually hits the disk. I'm willing to bet that in any halfway modern operating system, your proposed benchmark will *never* actually hit the disk, as long as you have more than, say, 4 GiByte of RAM. Note: this may, or may not be what you actually want, depending on what it is that you actually want to benchmark.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Can you propose a method to do what disk benchmarking programs are doing? I am getting similar (a little bit slower) speed results with my C# program compared to other benchmarking software on my 8GB RAM system, so I was assuming that my program is able to write the data and not caching. Shouldn't it be much faster if caching was going on since RAM is much faster compared to SSD?

Comment: There are many variables that affect disk access performance. Jorg has pointed out one-- the O/S-- and another huge one is antivirus. A proper benchmark program will use low level I/O, meaning you don't use any APIs at all. That sort of thing will probably need to be written the same way a disk driver is written-- in C++ or assembly. Although you could potentially use a C# front end.